visualizar scrollbar horizontal en vista de cakephp 4
estoy trabajando con cakephp4, en las vistas y según la resolucion de pantalla, se debe visualizar el scrollbar horizontal, cuando se recarga la vista aparece en la parte inferior de la pantalla, sin embargo al finalizar la carga se borra la barra de scroll y en el extremo inferior derecho aparece el icono de cakephp.
Saben ustedes que debo hacer para que no se borre la barra de scroll?

Hola Carlos, para que podamos ayudarte es necesarios que en tu pregunta incluyas un [mcve].

encontre la solucion. El mencionado icono corresponde al DebugKit de cake, pinchando en el se abre la barra de depuracion con sus funcionalidades, para que no salga hay que cambiar desde esto: 'debug' => env('ENVIRONMENT') == "development" ? true : false,
a esto: 'debug' => false,
el valor de 'ENVIRONMENT' se encuentra en las variables de entorno de windows.
Bueno, la variable 'debug' se encuentra en el archivo app.php en la ruta app/config de cakephp 4.
